# Scaling and centering image of varying dimensions, with right-aligned text in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a page where the image is on the left and the caption (the text) is on the right, and the image/text combo together centered on the page. The challenge I'm facing is that the image could be any size or aspect ratio. I need the image as big as possible (while still fitting in the screen without the user having to scroll). The image height can be determined using javascript (I'm using Angular). I've sketched out the three scenarios here:

[image]

The image could be in portrait orientation (height > width), landscape orientation (width > height), or a panoramic image (width > height, and width is abnormally wide). Some considerations for all three cases:

1. The caption/text should be fixed width (say 300px), and should be placed to the right of the image (and it should be visible, the user shouldn't have to scroll horizontally).
2. Image should be sized as big as possible--the height should be just less than the screen height (so no scroll bars). In the case of a panorama image, the height will be much less than the screen height, otherwise the text container will get pushed off the screen.
3. The image and text combo should be centered on the screen.

Hopefully, the sketch should clarify what I am trying to communicate here.

I am able to get the image and text side by side, but am not able to center them in all three scenarios.

```
<div class="right-side">
    {{ caption }} 
</div>

<div class="left-side">
    <img [src]="imageUrl">
</div>

.left-side {
    float: none; 
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;

    img {
        margin: 40px;
        margin-right: 0;
        max-height: 80vh; 
        max-width: 80vw;
    }
}

.right-side {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: In a mobile device, the layout will be the same?

Comment: No, this is just for desktop. Not concerned about mobile devices. You can assume the screen width will be greater than the screen height.

Comment: are you looking for something of that kind ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwNXNRB  if you need to filter portrait/landscape image , javascript will be required of from server side adding a class once ratio is checked out. CSS is at the moment unable to filter an image about its ratio .

Comment: @G-Cyr your solution seems to work pretty well. Trying to break it, will circle back.

Comment: @G-Cyr works pretty good, if you can convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go from my comment into an answer since it seems to be close to your needs .

grid could be used to center and reorder things at screen.

example :

```css
.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(auto, max-content));
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
}

.right-side {
  grid-column: 2;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.left-side {}

.left-side img {
  margin: 0 0 auto auto;/* will put at top right of its grid area */
  max-width: calc(100vw - 300px - 4em);
}


/* only for demo/possible way to break things into a single column*/

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .body {
    display: block;
  }
  .left-side img {
    margin: 0 0 auto auto;
    max-width: 90vw;
  }
  .right-side {
    max-width: 90vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="right-side">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p>
      <strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
      <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.
    </p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="left-side">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x400" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="right-side">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p>
      <strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
      <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.
    </p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="left-side">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x400" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="right-side">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p>
      <strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
      <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.
    </p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="left-side">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1400x600" />
  </div>
</div>
```

pen to play with : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/RwNXNRB

Answer (score 2):

CSS **Flexbox** has more cross-browser support over the CSS **Grid** system, here is an example with CSS object-fit used for image purposes only!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.article-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-side {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-side img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
}

.right-side {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="article-container">
    <div class="left-side">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZwaMNmO.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint magni voluptas laboriosam. Unde, est eos?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works in most cases, but for portrait orientation, the image-text combo is not centered...there is too much gap between the image and text.

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot of the portrait view? and sketch for how you want to looks like in portrait?

Answer (score 1):

let me explain my approach which for my understanding solves your requirement. First I declared left side and then declared right side in the HTML. I decided then to use flex for creating your grid and then making the image both responsive to landscape and portrait images. I'm assuming that your container will have a fixed width, but if you remove that static width it will work anyway (and you will have no need to add the margin: 0 auto; property).

I hope this solves your question and encourages you to use the power of flex!

```css
.left-side {  
    text-align: center;
}

.left-side img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90vh;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.right-side {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    flex: 0 0 300px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left-side">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1200">
</div>
<div class="right-side">
    {{ caption }} 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The centering works well, however, the image doesn't scale. Landscape oriented images look small on the screen even though there is a lot of room for it to be larger.

Comment: It's just a matter of adjusting max-height to the vh that fits you the most